# Not able to set Labels on xAxis on MPChartView android

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

I am not able to set labels on inverted chart View. I am using MPchart library for my graph. I have to show inverted graph with labels and ranks on the top according to the value. I am not able to set the labels at X-axis.

[image: I want my graph to show like this]

I want my graph to look like this. But I am not able to show labels and numbering on each graph.

What I am getting:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
   ArrayList<BarEntry> bargroup1 = new ArrayList<>();
    bargroup1.add(new BarEntry(12f, 4));
    bargroup1.add(new BarEntry(16f, 2));
    bargroup1.add(new BarEntry(20f, 1));
    bargroup1.add(new BarEntry(24f, 3));
    bargroup1.add(new BarEntry(28f, 5));

    ArrayList<BarEntry> bargroup2 = new ArrayList<>();
    bargroup2.add(new BarEntry(13f, 4));
    bargroup2.add(new BarEntry(17f, 2));
    bargroup2.add(new BarEntry(21f, 1));
    bargroup2.add(new BarEntry(25f, 3));
    bargroup2.add(new BarEntry(29f, 5));


    BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(bargroup1, "");


    barDataSet1.setColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.app_logo_color));

    BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(bargroup2, "");

    barDataSet2.setColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.app_grey_color));

    final ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

    labels.add("Buy");
    labels.add("Over");
    labels.add("Hold");
    labels.add("Under");
    labels.add("Sell");

    dataSets = new ArrayList<>();

    datasetdemo = new ArrayList<>();

    dataSets.add(barDataSet1);

    dataSets.add(barDataSet2);

    YAxis yAxisRight = barChart.getAxisRight();
    yAxisRight.setEnabled(false);
    YAxis yAxisLeft = barChart.getAxisLeft();
    yAxisLeft.setEnabled(false);

    // or use some other logic to save your data in list. For ex.

    XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
     xAxis.setEnabled(false);
    xAxis.setEnabled(false);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    barChart.invalidate();
    barChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
    barChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
    barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);

    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels));

    BarData data1 = new BarData(dataSets);

    barChart.setData(data1);
```

I have to show labels and numeric data on the top of each bar.

Comment: First of all, try to put barChart.invalidate() at the bottom, cause everything after invalidate() will not be applied on the chart

Comment: I did it, but still no label is coming.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the solution for the graph you want to achieve: (Below code allows you to group bars, invert graph as well show label below verticle bars when graph inverted)**

[image]

I have created my own "BarChartRendererMine" class which we will require to display label below inverted verticle bars. So create "BarChartRendererMine" class and copy paste below code:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.animation.ChartAnimator;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.buffer.BarBuffer;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.ValueFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.highlight.Highlight;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.highlight.Range;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.dataprovider.BarDataProvider;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.IBarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.model.GradientColor;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.BarLineScatterCandleBubbleRenderer;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.MPPointF;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Transformer;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Utils;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ViewPortHandler;

import java.util.List;

public class BarChartRendererMine extends BarLineScatterCandleBubbleRenderer {

    protected BarDataProvider mChart;

    Float commonY1 = 0f;

    /**
     * the rect object that is used for drawing the bars
     */
    protected RectF mBarRect = new RectF();

    protected BarBuffer[] mBarBuffers;

    protected Paint mShadowPaint;
    protected Paint mBarBorderPaint;

    public BarChartRendererMine(BarDataProvider chart, ChartAnimator animator,
                            ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        super(animator, viewPortHandler);
        this.mChart = chart;

        mHighlightPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mHighlightPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mHighlightPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
        // set alpha after color
        mHighlightPaint.setAlpha(120);

        mShadowPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mShadowPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        mBarBorderPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mBarBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    public void initBuffers() {

        BarData barData = mChart.getBarData();
        mBarBuffers = new BarBuffer[barData.getDataSetCount()];

        for (int i = 0; i < mBarBuffers.length; i++) {
            IBarDataSet set = barData.getDataSetByIndex(i);
            mBarBuffers[i] = new BarBuffer(set.getEntryCount() * 4 * (set.isStacked() ? set.getStackSize() : 1),
                    barData.getDataSetCount(), set.isStacked());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void drawData(Canvas c) {

        BarData barData = mChart.getBarData();

        for (int i = 0; i < barData.getDataSetCount(); i++) {

            IBarDataSet set = barData.getDataSetByIndex(i);

            if (set.isVisible()) {
                drawDataSet(c, set, i);
            }

        }
    }

    private RectF mBarShadowRectBuffer = new RectF();

    protected void drawDataSet(Canvas c, IBarDataSet dataSet, int index) {

        Transformer trans = mChart.getTransformer(dataSet.getAxisDependency());

        mBarBorderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getBarBorderColor());
        mBarBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(Utils.convertDpToPixel(dataSet.getBarBorderWidth()));

        final boolean drawBorder = dataSet.getBarBorderWidth() > 0.f;

        float phaseX = mAnimator.getPhaseX();
        float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY();

        // draw the bar shadow before the values
        if (mChart.isDrawBarShadowEnabled()) {
            mShadowPaint.setColor(dataSet.getBarShadowColor());

            BarData barData = mChart.getBarData();

            final float barWidth = barData.getBarWidth();
            final float barWidthHalf = barWidth / 2.0f;
            float x;


            for (int i = 0, count = Math.min((int) (Math.ceil((float) (dataSet.getEntryCount()) * phaseX)), dataSet.getEntryCount());
                 i < count;
                 i++) {

                BarEntry e = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(i);
                x = e.getX();

                mBarShadowRectBuffer.left = x - barWidthHalf;
                mBarShadowRectBuffer.right = x + barWidthHalf;

                trans.rectValueToPixel(mBarShadowRectBuffer);

                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(mBarShadowRectBuffer.right))
                    continue;

                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(mBarShadowRectBuffer.left))
                    break;

                mBarShadowRectBuffer.top = mViewPortHandler.contentTop();
                mBarShadowRectBuffer.bottom = mViewPortHandler.contentBottom();

                c.drawRect(mBarShadowRectBuffer, mShadowPaint);
            }
        }

        // initialize the buffer
        BarBuffer buffer = mBarBuffers[index];
        buffer.setPhases(phaseX, phaseY);
        buffer.setDataSet(index);
        buffer.setInverted(mChart.isInverted(dataSet.getAxisDependency()));
        buffer.setBarWidth(mChart.getBarData().getBarWidth());

        buffer.feed(dataSet);

        trans.pointValuesToPixel(buffer.buffer);

        final boolean isSingleColor = dataSet.getColors().size() == 1;

        if (isSingleColor) {
            mRenderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor());
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < buffer.size(); j += 4) {

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(buffer.buffer[j + 2]))
                continue;

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(buffer.buffer[j]))
                break;

            if (!isSingleColor) {
                // Set the color for the currently drawn value. If the index
                // is out of bounds, reuse colors.
                mRenderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor(j / 4));
            }

            if (dataSet.getGradientColor() != null) {
                GradientColor gradientColor = dataSet.getGradientColor();
                mRenderPaint.setShader(
                        new LinearGradient(
                                buffer.buffer[j],
                                buffer.buffer[j + 3],
                                buffer.buffer[j],
                                buffer.buffer[j + 1],
                                gradientColor.getStartColor(),
                                gradientColor.getEndColor(),
                                android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
            }

            if (dataSet.getGradientColors() != null) {
                mRenderPaint.setShader(
                        new LinearGradient(
                                buffer.buffer[j],
                                buffer.buffer[j + 3],
                                buffer.buffer[j],
                                buffer.buffer[j + 1],
                                dataSet.getGradientColor(j / 4).getStartColor(),
                                dataSet.getGradientColor(j / 4).getEndColor(),
                                android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
            }

            c.drawRect(buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                    buffer.buffer[j + 3], mRenderPaint);

            if (drawBorder) {
                c.drawRect(buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 3], mBarBorderPaint);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void prepareBarHighlight(float x, float y1, float y2, float barWidthHalf, Transformer trans) {

        float left = x - barWidthHalf;
        float right = x + barWidthHalf;
        float top = y1;
        float bottom = y2;

        mBarRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);

        trans.rectToPixelPhase(mBarRect, mAnimator.getPhaseY());
    }

    @Override
    public void drawValues(Canvas c) {

        // if values are drawn
        if (isDrawingValuesAllowed(mChart)) {

            List<IBarDataSet> dataSets = mChart.getBarData().getDataSets();

            final float valueOffsetPlus = Utils.convertDpToPixel(4.5f);
            float posOffset = 0f;
            float negOffset = 0f;
            boolean drawValueAboveBar = mChart.isDrawValueAboveBarEnabled();

            for (int i = 0; i < mChart.getBarData().getDataSetCount(); i++) {

                IBarDataSet dataSet = dataSets.get(i);

                if (!shouldDrawValues(dataSet))
                    continue;

                // apply the text-styling defined by the DataSet
                applyValueTextStyle(dataSet);

                // calculate the correct offset depending on the draw position of
                // the value
                float valueTextHeight = Utils.calcTextHeight(mValuePaint, "8");
                posOffset = (drawValueAboveBar ? -valueOffsetPlus : valueTextHeight + valueOffsetPlus);
                negOffset = (drawValueAboveBar ? valueTextHeight + valueOffsetPlus : -valueOffsetPlus);

                // get the buffer
                BarBuffer buffer = mBarBuffers[i];

                final float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY();

                ValueFormatter formatter = dataSet.getValueFormatter();

                MPPointF iconsOffset = MPPointF.getInstance(dataSet.getIconsOffset());
                iconsOffset.x = Utils.convertDpToPixel(iconsOffset.x);
                iconsOffset.y = Utils.convertDpToPixel(iconsOffset.y);

                // if only single values are drawn (sum)
                if (!dataSet.isStacked()) {

                    commonY1 = 0f;
                    for (int j = 0; j < buffer.buffer.length * mAnimator.getPhaseX(); j += 4) {

                        float x = (buffer.buffer[j] + buffer.buffer[j + 2]) / 2f;

                        if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(x))
                            break;

                        if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsY(buffer.buffer[j + 1])
                                || !mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(x))
                            continue;

                        BarEntry entry = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(j / 4);
                        float val = entry.getY();

                        if (dataSet.isDrawValuesEnabled()) {
                            commonY1 = (buffer.buffer[j + 3] + negOffset);
                            drawValue(c, formatter.getBarLabel(entry), x, val >= 0 ?
                                            (buffer.buffer[j + 1] + posOffset) :
                                            (buffer.buffer[j + 3] + negOffset),
                                    dataSet.getValueTextColor(j / 4));
                        }

                        if (entry.getIcon() != null && dataSet.isDrawIconsEnabled()) {

                            Drawable icon = entry.getIcon();

                            float px = x;
                            float py = val >= 0 ?
                                    (buffer.buffer[j + 1] + posOffset) :
                                    (buffer.buffer[j + 3] + negOffset);

                            px += iconsOffset.x;
                            py += iconsOffset.y;

                            Utils.drawImage(
                                    c,
                                    icon,
                                    (int) px,
                                    (int) py,
                                    icon.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                                    icon.getIntrinsicHeight());
                        }
                    }

                    // if we have stacks
                } else {

                    Transformer trans = mChart.getTransformer(dataSet.getAxisDependency());

                    int bufferIndex = 0;
                    int index = 0;

                    while (index < dataSet.getEntryCount() * mAnimator.getPhaseX()) {

                        BarEntry entry = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(index);

                        float[] vals = entry.getYVals();
                        float x = (buffer.buffer[bufferIndex] + buffer.buffer[bufferIndex + 2]) / 2f;

                        int color = dataSet.getValueTextColor(index);

                        // we still draw stacked bars, but there is one
                        // non-stacked
                        // in between
                        if (vals == null) {

                            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(x))
                                break;

                            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsY(buffer.buffer[bufferIndex + 1])
                                    || !mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(x))
                                continue;

                            if (dataSet.isDrawValuesEnabled()) {
                                drawValue(c, formatter.getBarLabel(entry), x, buffer.buffer[bufferIndex + 1] +
                                                (entry.getY() >= 0 ? posOffset : negOffset),
                                        color);
                            }

                            if (entry.getIcon() != null && dataSet.isDrawIconsEnabled()) {

                                Drawable icon = entry.getIcon();

                                float px = x;
                                float py = buffer.buffer[bufferIndex + 1] +
                                        (entry.getY() >= 0 ? posOffset : negOffset);

                                px += iconsOffset.x;
                                py += iconsOffset.y;

                                Utils.drawImage(
                                        c,
                                        icon,
                                        (int) px,
                                        (int) py,
                                        icon.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                                        icon.getIntrinsicHeight());
                            }

                            // draw stack values
                        } else {

                            float[] transformed = new float[vals.length * 2];

                            float posY = 0f;
                            float negY = -entry.getNegativeSum();

                            for (int k = 0, idx = 0; k < transformed.length; k += 2, idx++) {

                                float value = vals[idx];
                                float y;

                                if (value == 0.0f && (posY == 0.0f || negY == 0.0f)) {
                                    // Take care of the situation of a 0.0 value, which overlaps a non-zero bar
                                    y = value;
                                } else if (value >= 0.0f) {
                                    posY += value;
                                    y = posY;
                                } else {
                                    y = negY;
                                    negY -= value;
                                }

                                transformed[k + 1] = y * phaseY;
                            }

                            trans.pointValuesToPixel(transformed);

                            for (int k = 0; k < transformed.length; k += 2) {

                                final float val = vals[k / 2];
                                final boolean drawBelow =
                                        (val == 0.0f && negY == 0.0f && posY > 0.0f) ||
                                                val < 0.0f;
                                float y = transformed[k + 1]
                                        + (drawBelow ? negOffset : posOffset);

                                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(x))
                                    break;

                                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsY(y)
                                        || !mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(x))
                                    continue;

                                if (dataSet.isDrawValuesEnabled()) {
                                    drawValue(c, formatter.getBarStackedLabel(val, entry), x, y, color);
                                }

                                if (entry.getIcon() != null && dataSet.isDrawIconsEnabled()) {

                                    Drawable icon = entry.getIcon();

                                    Utils.drawImage(
                                            c,
                                            icon,
                                            (int) (x + iconsOffset.x),
                                            (int) (y + iconsOffset.y),
                                            icon.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                                            icon.getIntrinsicHeight());
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        bufferIndex = vals == null ? bufferIndex + 4 : bufferIndex + 4 * vals.length;
                        index++;
                    }
                }

                MPPointF.recycleInstance(iconsOffset);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void drawValue(Canvas c, String valueText, float x, float y, int color) {
        mValuePaint.setColor(color);
        try{
            c.drawText(valueText, x, commonY1 + 30f, mValuePaint);
        }catch (Exception e){
            c.drawText(valueText, x, y, mValuePaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void drawHighlighted(Canvas c, Highlight[] indices) {

        BarData barData = mChart.getBarData();

        for (Highlight high : indices) {

            IBarDataSet set = barData.getDataSetByIndex(high.getDataSetIndex());

            if (set == null || !set.isHighlightEnabled())
                continue;

            BarEntry e = set.getEntryForXValue(high.getX(), high.getY());

            if (!isInBoundsX(e, set))
                continue;

            Transformer trans = mChart.getTransformer(set.getAxisDependency());

            mHighlightPaint.setColor(set.getHighLightColor());
            mHighlightPaint.setAlpha(set.getHighLightAlpha());

            boolean isStack = (high.getStackIndex() >= 0 && e.isStacked()) ? true : false;

            final float y1;
            final float y2;

            if (isStack) {

                if (mChart.isHighlightFullBarEnabled()) {

                    y1 = e.getPositiveSum();
                    y2 = -e.getNegativeSum();

                } else {

                    Range range = e.getRanges()[high.getStackIndex()];

                    y1 = range.from;
                    y2 = range.to;

                }

            } else {
                y1 = e.getY();
                y2 = 0.f;

            }

            prepareBarHighlight(e.getX(), y1, y2, barData.getBarWidth() / 2f, trans);

            setHighlightDrawPos(high, mBarRect);

            c.drawRect(mBarRect, mHighlightPaint);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the drawing position of the highlight object based on the riven bar-rect.
     *
     * @param high
     */
    protected void setHighlightDrawPos(Highlight high, RectF bar) {
        high.setDraw(bar.centerX(), bar.top);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawExtras(Canvas c) {
    }
}
```

Then in our activity do as below:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.a.mpandroidchartbarwidth.custom.BarChartRendererMine;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.animation.ChartAnimator;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.AxisBase;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Legend;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IAxisValueFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IValueFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IndexAxisValueFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.LargeValueFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.ValueFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.dataprovider.BarDataProvider;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.IBarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.BarChartRenderer;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ViewPortHandler;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class BarChartInvertedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BarChart barChart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setTitle("BarChartActivity");

        barChart = findViewById(R.id.barchart);

        float barWidth = 0.2f;
        float barSpace = 0.1f;
        float groupSpace = 0.25f;
        int groupCount = 2;

        ArrayList xVals = new ArrayList();

        xVals.add("Hold");
        xVals.add("Over");
        xVals.add("Buy");

        ArrayList<String> yValsTop = new ArrayList();
        yValsTop.add("0");
        yValsTop.add("1");
        yValsTop.add("2");
        yValsTop.add("3");
        yValsTop.add("4");
        yValsTop.add("5");
        yValsTop.add("6");
        yValsTop.add("7");
        yValsTop.add("8");

        ArrayList yVals1 = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList yVals2 = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList yVals3 = new ArrayList();

        yVals1.add(new BarEntry(1, (float) 1));
        yVals2.add(new BarEntry(1, (float) 2));

        yVals1.add(new BarEntry(2, (float) 3));
        yVals2.add(new BarEntry(2, (float) 4));

        yVals1.add(new BarEntry(3, (float) 5));
        yVals2.add(new BarEntry(3, (float) 6));

        BarDataSet set1, set2, set3;
        set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "Buy");
        set1.setColor(Color.parseColor("#3EBB9B"));
        set2 = new BarDataSet(yVals2, "Sell");
        set2.setColor(Color.parseColor("#3698DB"));

        set1.setDrawValues(true);
        set2.setDrawValues(true);
        BarData data1 = new BarData(set1, set2);

        barChart.setData(data1);
        barChart.getBarData().setBarWidth(barWidth);
        barChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(0);
        barChart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(0 + barChart.getBarData().getGroupWidth(groupSpace, barSpace) * groupCount);
        barChart.getData().setHighlightEnabled(false);
        barChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
        barChart.invalidate();

        barChart.setDescription(null);
        barChart.setPinchZoom(false);
        barChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
        barChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
        barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

        //X-axis
        XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
        xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
        xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xAxis.setAxisMaximum(3);
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP);
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xVals));

        //Y-axis
        barChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
        YAxis leftAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
        leftAxis.setSpaceTop(35f);
        leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);


        YAxis yAxisRight = barChart.getAxisRight();
        yAxisRight.setEnabled(false);
        YAxis yAxisLeft = barChart.getAxisLeft();
        yAxisLeft.setEnabled(false);

        barChart.groupBars(groupSpace, groupSpace, barSpace);
        barChart.getAxisLeft().setInverted(true);
        barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);

        BarChartRendererMine barChartCustomRenderer = new BarChartRendererMine(barChart, barChart.getAnimator(), barChart.getViewPortHandler());
        barChart.setRenderer(barChartCustomRenderer);
        xAxis.setAxisLineColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTransparent));


    }

}
```

This will change  line color and looks like hidden

```
"xAxis.setAxisLineColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTransparent));"
```

Below lines required to custom draw for bar chart:

```
BarChartRendererMine barChartCustomRenderer = new BarChartRendererMine(barChart, barChart.getAnimator(), barChart.getViewPortHandler());
barChart.setRenderer(barChartCustomRenderer);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. This is showing the lables, but how can I rotate it.

Comment: do you want to rotate "buy", "hold" and "over" values or bar values?

Comment: I want to rotate the graph as in the image.

Comment: i can't see any rotation in image. can you clarify please?

Comment: I want to rotate the graph by 180 degree. I am getting the graph upwards, I want it to be downwards.

Comment: my above code is the same for inverted graph means it will rotate graph with 180 degree. but still let me clear you that by writing this line "     barChart.getAxisLeft().setInverted(true);" the graph will rotate 180

Comment: I am getting inverted graph. It was my mistake, I had added rotation in xml. Is there a way to show only one bar value for both, Like the one I have shown in image.

Comment: I am getting values and the graph now. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: yes we can show only one value for both but for it i have to edit "BarChartRendererMine" class

Comment: Labels are not properly coming in between the two bars. Some are coming in between, some are slightly moved rightwards.

Comment: for that you have to adjust these four values "barWidth, barSpace, groupSpace, groupCount". because there will be different groupcounts

Comment: I did it. If I want to set custom Values, do I need to change them in "BarChartRendererMine" because "setValueFormatter" is not working.

Comment: are you asking for bar values like "1.00", "2.00" etc or "hold", "sell" custom values you want to change?

Comment: 1 in place of 1:00.

Comment: replace "drawValue(c, String.valueOf((int) Float.parseFloat(formatter.getBarLabel(entry))), x, val >= 0 ?
                                            (buffer.buffer[j + 1] + posOffset) :
                                            (buffer.buffer[j + 3] + negOffset),
                                    dataSet.getValueTextColor(j / 4));"    wherever  drawValue() method called. For example its calling in line no. 279, 337, 408 in BarChartRendererMine